# How to set language to Arabic in Telligent 5.5 (Zimbra)?

Tags: zimbra, telligent

I am using Telligent 5.5 (Zimbra) and want to use Cyrillic and Arabic for our communities. How do I do that?

Comment: if it is not in the default language, you can probably download the language pack and then go in the settings to select it.